# Suggestion popup-menu drracket

Tags: scheme, racket

im using Racket graphical toolkit and i'm trying to show a suggestion popup menu.

I have a list of available strings to select from and i want to show them in a popup menu as you write in a text-field.

I have managed to show them but you have to re select the text-field to continue writing. And every time you select the text-field the popup menu goes away.

Is this even possible? if so how can i achieve this?

here is a little example to explain my self better:

```
(define (prueba)
  (let* ((ventana (new frame% (label "")))
     (sugerencia (new popup-menu%))
     (texto (new text-field% (label "prueba")(parent ventana)
                (callback (lambda (t e)
                            (new menu-item% (label (send t get-value))(parent sugerencia)
                                    (callback (lambda (i e) (void))))
                             (send ventana popup-menu sugerencia (+ 50 (send t get-x)) (+(send t get-height)(send t get-y))))))))
   (send ventana show #t)))
```

Comment: It's best to ask these kind of questions on our [mailing list](http://racket-lang.org/community.html) since there are more people who know the GUI system well enough there.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use a `popup-menu%` here, that's for the kind of contextual menus that you get from right-clicking.  Instead, you should just create a new window (or maybe just a new `frame%` which will have the appropriate callbacks to insert suggestions into the main `frame%`.